# How to fix ffmpeg freezes when running large transcoding with upscaling?

Tags: ffmpeg

Every time that I try to perform an expensive (computer resource wise) `ffmpeg` transcoding, including size upscaling, Ubuntu freezes.

Example Command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset slow -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ac 4 -vf scale=w=1920:h=1408,format=yuv420p output.mp4
```

I have no idea how to debug this issue, and I am not sure if it is a hardware or a software problem.

When I ran the same command on a Intel laptop, it finished without freezing and on the machine in question it does not freeze when performing a transcoding with the same input file but without size upscaling.

Here are my system details:

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- Mobo: Asus 970 Pro Gaming/Aura
- CPU: Amd FX 8350
- RAM: 16 Gb HyperX (2x8Gb)
- HD: Inter 600p M.2
- Graphics: Nvidia 750 Ti
- `ffmpeg` version 3.3.1-1~16.04.york0

Temperature as provided by `psensor` never goes beyond 60° Celsius, but CPU usage is all the time between 98-100% usage when running the task.

Comment: - Have you monitored temps on the cpu?  
- Try running the transcode in a guest VM and see what happens.  
- Try a different non-ubuntu based distro like fedora or antergos and see what happens.
If the results are consistent then it's a hardware problem.

Comment: Could you please install a supported version of FFmpeg (i. e. `7:2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`) and try again? Custom packages including those from third-party package repositories aren't well supported here.

Comment: @DanglingPointer Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Created a quick VM and I manage to get the job done without crashing the host. I added up to 4 CPUs to it and host CPU usage about 60% and about 100% for each of the 4 core committed to the task. Maybe that's why my system freezed when running the task directly on the host, all 8 cores were constantly used at between 98 - 100% usage as well as the whole system resources.